# For Each Loop SelectionStart Doesnt Work

Tags: vb.net

Following code works great;

```
    For Each c As Control In TabPage1.Controls
        If Not TypeOf c Is Label Then
            c.Enabled = False
        End If
    Next
```

Following code works great;

```
    TextBox1.SelectionStart = 0
```

Following code doesnt work;

```
    For Each c As Control In TabPage1.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is TextBox Then
            c.SelectionStart = 0
        End If
    Next
```

This is the error message;

'SelectionStart' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `c` variable has type `Control`. The base `Control` type does not have a `SelectionStart` property. You need some mechanism to cast this to a `TextBox`.

I recommend using the `OfType()` method, which will also handle the `if()` conditional, resulting in less overall code:

```
For Each c As TextBox In TabPage1.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
    c.SelectionStart = 0
Next c
```

But you could also go for the more conventional `DirectCast()`:

```
For Each c As Control In TabPage1.Controls
    If TypeOf c Is TextBox Then
        Dim t As TextBox = DirectCast(c, TextBox)
        t.SelectionStart = 0
    End If
Next
```

Or the `TryCast()` option:

```
For Each c As Control In TabPage1.Controls
    Dim t As TextBox = TryCast(c, TextBox)
    If t IsNot Nothing Then
        t.SelectionStart = 0
    End If
Next
```